# Examine contents of a nuget package

Tags: nuget

Is there a way to examine the contents of a NuGet package to see what changes it will be making? There is no option for this on the Nuget.exe command line and I do not find any information about this in the NuGet docs.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`.nupkg` files are just ZIP files with some metadata, so you can have a look at the contents. The [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) should make it a little easier to view the contents.

The NuGet Gallery (e.g. https://www.nuget.org/) has a "Download" link on the right hand side, otherwise just install the package into an empty project and then take a peek.

Comment: so you are saying the nupkg file is zipped version of dlls?

Comment: @Antoops yes, it is a ZIP file with DLLs and some metadata (i.e. the nuspec)

Answer (score 56):

### Windows Users:

As Jonathon Rossi pointed out,

> .nupkg files are just ZIP files, so you can have a look at the contents

So on a windows machine, for a temporary fix, just change the file extension from `.nupkg` to `.zip`, and then just use Windows' `File Explorer` to leverage the existing file association for `.zip` (`CompressedFolder`) files.

It is possible to "permanently" associate `.nupkg` with your system's `CompressedFolder` tool.  However, this will corrupt the `IconCache.db` at the very least, and the typical method to restore it does not work for me (deleting the `IconCache.db` and rebooting).  So I would recommend ***against*** associating `.nupkg` with `CompressedFolder` if you are concerned with seeing the correct file icon in `File Explorer`.

With that in mind, if you want a longer term solution for opening `.nupkg` files without changing their extension...

You can set a file association easily via a command prompt (`cmd`) like so:

[image]

These files will now have the same icon as any other `CompressedFolder` on your file system, and you can leave their extensions unchanged (as `.nupkg`).

To undo this association, repeat `assoc` command for the `.nupkg` but leave the RHS blank:

[image]

You can confirm the current file association at any time by running `assoc .nupkg`, **dropping the equals sign (`=`).**:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me - but I had to run the command window as an administrator. If only windows had a sudo command.

Comment: Windows also has the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) which will let you peek at the manifest without downloading it.

Comment: For copy-n-paste: 
assoc .nupkg=CompressedFolder

Answer (score 7):

Another solution would be to use [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

It has an option to decompile packages from NuGet directly and NuGet caches.

[image: Screenshot from DotPeek]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to inspect the metadata for the package, to check the dependencies and to view the readme file, you can go to nuget.com and start the upload process: https://www.nuget.org/packages/manage/upload

The verification section of that page will show you all the metadata.